# C2371: 'mxArray' : redefinition; different basic types

Tags: c, matlab, compiler-construction

Im trying to MEX piece of code with VS 2010 MATLAB 2012b and getting this error

c:\users\krzysztof\desktop\libocas_v096\libocas_v096\sparse_mat.h(27) : error C2371: 'mxArray' : redefinition; different basic types
        c:\program files\matlab\r2012b\extern\include\matrix.h(293) : see declaration of 'mxArray'

the code contains #include  which includes matrix.h

another piece code includes sparse_mat.h which redefines matrix.h types e.g.

```
typedef struct {
  INDEX_TYPE_T *ir;
  INDEX_TYPE_T *jc;
  INDEX_TYPE_T m;
  INDEX_TYPE_T n;
  double *pr;
  NNZ_TYPE_T nzmax;
  int sparse;

} mxArray;
```

Any idea how to get rid of this error ?? GCC compiles this code.

Krzysztof

it complains about line 293. Below part from matrix.h with this line

```
#ifndef MATHWORKS_MATRIX_MXARRAY_PUB_FWD_H
#define MATHWORKS_MATRIX_MXARRAY_PUB_FWD_H

/* Copyright 2008 The MathWorks, Inc. */

/**
 * Published incomplete definition of mxArray
 */
typedef struct mxArray_tag mxArray; <--- line 293

#endif /* MATHWORKS_MATRIX_MXARRAY_PUB_FWD_H */
```

Comment: Redefinition of structures isn't legal C.  If GCC accepts the code, it's being pretty nice to you.  Can you show both structure definitions?

Comment: it complains about line 293. Below part from matrix.h with this line                                                                  ` #ifndef MATHWORKS_MATRIX_MXARRAY_PUB_FWD_H
#define MATHWORKS_MATRIX_MXARRAY_PUB_FWD_H

/* Copyright 2008 The MathWorks, Inc. */

/**
 * Published incomplete definition of mxArray
 */
typedef struct mxArray_tag mxArray; <--- line 293

#endif /* MATHWORKS_MATRIX_MXARRAY_PUB_FWD_H */`

Comment: And why do you want to redefine it?

Comment: I'm not an author but just sent to author the email with the same question. Perhaps renaming should be enough

Comment: Could you try to rename your struct from mxArray? It's already defined. This should solve your issue.

Comment: This looks like the third party library libocas library is reimplementing some of the standard Matlab functions, maybe for use in the "standalone application" mode when the MEX libraries are not linked (http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~xfrancv/ocas/html/). I suspect that when compiling in MEX context, you don't want to have that `sparse_mat.h` and `sparse_mat.c` from libocas included at all. Maybe there's a compilation option to exclude them? Or maybe the libocas header's guard code is for a different version of Matlab - is libocas 0.96 compatible with Matlab R2012b?

Comment: How are you trying to build the MEX files? Can you include the compiler commands or build steps in your problem description?

Comment: When you say "GCC compiles this code", do you mean it works when you do exactly what you're doing now on the same machine, just substituting GCC for VS, or do you mean running `make`, maybe on Linux, which then calls GCC? The Makefile targets in libocas define `-DLIBOCAS_MATLAB`, which causes the ocas headers to not include `sparse_mat.h`, and use Matlab's `<mex.h>` instead, so there's no conflict. You probably need to get the same thing to happen with what you're building.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include header `"mex.h"` instead of `"matrix.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you aren't using the `forward declaration` correctly.

In

```
typedef struct {
  INDEX_TYPE_T *ir;
  INDEX_TYPE_T *jc;
  INDEX_TYPE_T m;
  INDEX_TYPE_T n;
  double *pr;
  NNZ_TYPE_T nzmax;
  int sparse;

} mxArray;
```

You're defining a new type called `mxArray`.

In

```
typedef struct mxArray_tag mxArray;
```

You are aliasing a type `struct mxArray_tag` to `mxArray` which collides witch the `mxArray` that you've already defined.

According to the comment in your code you're trying to declare an `mxArray` type by forward declaration. The correct way to do this for your code would be `typedef mxArray mxArray_tag;`. Or, more naturally, you could change the full type definition of your `mxArray` not to be an anonymous struct:

```
typedef struct _mxArray {
  INDEX_TYPE_T *ir;
  INDEX_TYPE_T *jc;
  INDEX_TYPE_T m;
  INDEX_TYPE_T n;
  double *pr;
  NNZ_TYPE_T nzmax;
  int sparse;

} mxArray;
```

and the forward declaration will be `typedef struct _mxArray mxArray;`.